# What is the best testing approach and test designs techniques, that suites for gambling software testing with technical standards?

Tags: test-design, quality-assurance, combinatorial-testing, testing-strategies

What is the best testing approach that suites to test a gambling software.

Specifically, what should I do *in addition* to normal functional testing? I am looking for answers that are specific to the gambling industry.

Also I would like to know about the test designs techniques that suites for this kind of software,

Comment: Have you spoken to lawyers about this?  State law often specifies certain requirements when it comes to games of chance.

Comment: Which country are you in, or testing for? Gambling and gambling machines are heavily regulated in the UK, but will require different tests and use cases compared to, say, the USA for example.

Answer (score 1):

As this software is designed to part people with their money, the focus has to be on the user experience and the financial transactions.
In terms of risk you'd want automated tests to check

- game rules are correctly implemented
- server scales with load
- money can be moved/added to the account
- lag and disconnections are correctly handled - users really go ape
  over being roasted by those kind of things

Comment: As gambling software is often based on random numbers, you might add a test for sufficient randomness and that it isn't skewed in favor of the user.